# The input stream is empty after processing, tip: check stream validity

Tags: c#, .net

I have below 3 methods to ingest data from a ConcurrentBag to Kusto (Azure Data Explorer). It works like charm in .NET Core. But it is not ow working in .NET Framework. It is failing with error

> The input stream is empty after processing, tip:check stream validity

Can someone please suggest how to overcome the empty stream error

```html
public static void DSCMKustoBulkIngest(ILogger logger, AppSettings AppConfig)
        {
            if (DSCMJITPoliciesCollection.Count != 0)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < DSCMJITPoliciesCollection.Count; l += 100)
                {
                    List<DSCMJITPoliciesModel> results = DSCMJITPoliciesCollection.Skip(l).Take(100).ToList();
                    DSCMIngestToKusto(results, AppConfig, logger);
                }
                logger.LogInformation(DSCMJITPoliciesCollection.Count + $"- Total DSCM Records ingested into DSCMJITPoliciesSnapshot Kusto Table: {DateTime.Now}");
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"No Records to Ingest into Kusto: {DateTime.Now}");
                ServicesCount = 0;
            }
        }

        private static string DSCMIngestToKusto(List<DSCMJITPoliciesModel> DSCMJITPoliciesCollection, AppSettings AppConfig, ILogger logger)
        {
            Stream stream = CreateDSCMJsonStream(DSCMJITPoliciesCollection);
            var KustoConnectionStringBuilderEngine = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(AppConfig.KustoClusterFQDN)
                .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(applicationClientId: AppConfig.KustoAppClientID, applicationKey: RAMPCommon.KeyVault
                .GetSecret(AppConfig.KustoAppKey, AppConfig, logger), authority: AppConfig.AMETenantID);
            CreateJsonMappingIfNotExists(KustoConnectionStringBuilderEngine, AppConfig.KustoDataBaseName, "DSCMJITPoliciesSnapshot");

            using (var siClient = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslStreamIngestClient(KustoConnectionStringBuilderEngine))
            {
                siClient.ExecuteStreamIngestAsync(
                    AppConfig.KustoDataBaseName,
                    "DSCMJITPoliciesSnapshot",
                    stream,
                    null,
                    DataSourceFormat.json,
                    compressStream: false,
                    mappingName: s_DSCMjsonMappingName).ResultEx();
            }            
            return "Success";
        }

        private static Stream CreateDSCMJsonStream(List<DSCMJITPoliciesModel> DSCMJITPoliciesCollection)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (var tw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8, 4096, true))
            {
                foreach (DSCMJITPoliciesModel R in DSCMJITPoliciesCollection)
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("{{'ServiceGroupName':'{0}', 'TeamGroupName':'{1}', 'ServiceName':'{2}', 'ServiceTreeID':'{3}', 'Level':'{4}', 'SOX':'{5}','ResourceType':'{6}', " +
                        "'PolicyID':'{7}' ,'PolicyType':'{8}', 'Environment':'{9}' , 'ConditionName':'{10}', 'RequestorGroups':'{11}', 'AccessLevels':'{12}', 'IcMTeamNames':'{13}'" +
                        ",'ApprovalPeriod':'{14}', 'NotifyEmail':'{15}' , 'Compliant':'{16}' ,'Action':'{17}' ,'CollectionTime':'{18}' ,'RowID':'{19}' ,'RunID':'{20}'}}",
                                  R.ServiceGroupName, R.TeamGroupName, R.ServiceName, R.ServiceTreeID, R.Level, R.SOX, R.ResourceType,
                                  R.PolicyID, R.PolicyType, R.Environment, R.ConditionName, R.RequestorGroups, R.AccessLevels, R.IcMTeamNames,
                                  R.ApprovalPeriod, R.NotifyEmail, R.Compliant, R.Action, R.CollectionTime, R.RowID, R.RunID);
                }
            }
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return ms;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It was due to an invalid character. Apparently Kusto does not allow "\" in input stream.